# unknown command error when loading .tmux.conf

Tags: linux, tmux

So I made my ~/.tmux.conf as suggested in other threads in two different ways

```
tmux show -g | cat > ~/.tmux.conf
tmux show -g > ~/.tmux.conf
```

I tested them both and they both give me an error:

`/root/.tmux.conf:25: unknown command:` followed by every setting when loading from the first line to the second to last  line, the last line being the binding that I added:

`bind -n C-x setw synchronize-panes`

Good news is that my binding works...

I have zero idea what is causing the error, but the fact that my binding works makes me think that you might only want to add additional configurations other then the default in the .tmux.conf

Any help with this issue or clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It appears `tmux.conf` syntax has changed and these commands no longer generate a syntactically valid file.

To convert options shown by `tmux show -g` to valid tmux commands you need to add `set-option -g` (shorter alias: `set -g`) in front of each one. Run this command in a `tmux` session:

```
tmux show -g | sed 's/^/set -g /' > ~/.tmux.conf
```

---

Note: one of the lines my `tmux show -g` generates is `prefix2 <NONE>` which seems to be invalid later. Just remove it if you need, many other lines should be fine. My `tmux` version is 2.1-3build1 in Kubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.